# How to install Gist plugin for Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, gist

I want install [Gist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2423) plugin for Vim.

I have tried the following:

1. Download the file [gist-vim.zip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=17345).
2. Extract ZIP archive and copy `plugin/gist.vim` to `.vim/plugin/gist.vim`.

But running `:Gist` in Vim fails:

```
E117: Unknown function: gist#Gist
```

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That plugin also has files in .vim/autoload and .vim/doc, did you install those as well?  I see this in .vim/autoload/gist.vim:

```
...

function! gist#Gist(count, line1, line2, ...)
...
```